# Calculating richtextbox lines count asynchronously

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, richtextbox, statusstrip

I write a code that counts the number of lines and text length from richtextbox content. With small chunks of text it work perfect. But when there large chunks of text (more than 100k) when I press "Enter" or "Backspace" in richtextbox, response time becomes very slow. For example: https://i.imgur.com/QO2UrAw.gifv

**My question. What a better way to run this code asynchronously?**

*Archive with the test project* https://gofile.io/?c=LpF409

```
private void StatusPanelTextInfo()
{
    int currentColumn = 0;
    int currentLine = 0;
    int linesCount = 0;
    if (statusStrip1.Visible)
    {
        currentColumn = 1 + richTextBox1.SelectionStart - richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox
        {
            WordWrap = false,
            Text = richTextBox1.Text
        };
        currentLine = 1 + rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);
        linesCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();
        if (linesCount == 0)
        {
            linesCount = 1;
        }
    }
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Length: " + richTextBox1.TextLength;
    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Lines: " + linesCount;
    toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = "Ln: " + currentLine;
    toolStripStatusLabel4.Text = "Col: " + currentColumn;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You're creating a new RichTextBox control on every (I assume) key press, and never dispose of it explicitly. You don't need it. Check the number of chars in each line and see in which line the current SelectionStart value is contained. Change `linesCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();` in `linesCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Length`.

Comment: The logical column follows the same *logic*, add a subtraction. As a note, the RTB uses just `\n` to mark a new line, not `\r\n` (so, just 1 char).

Comment: @Jimi I creating a new RichTextBox control for correct calculating line count when word wrap is on in richTextBox1 But even if I delete this code, It still cause slow response in big chunks of text.

Comment: @Jimi I found out that I only have  slow response when calculating the number of lines.

Comment: You have a *slow response* because of the method you're using to calculate `currentLine`. Read again my first comment (including the `linesCount` part).

Comment: @Jimi Ok, I changed `linesCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();` in `linesCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Length` and removed `currentLine` and I still have a slow response, in file that have 1 million characters.

Comment: I just tested a RichTextBox (`50W`), adding 1000 lines of text where each line repeats the pattern `"Some Test String "` 1000 times, for a total `17,001,000` chars (including the `\n` char). Not a champ, but no really highly noticeable *slow downs*. What version of the Framework are you using (tested on `Net 4.8`)? Note that `RTB 50W` is part of .Net 4.7.1+. Otherwise you have the `20W` version. It gets slower when you have a lot of different selections with different Fonts.

Comment: @ I'm using 4.7.2 

I'm attached test project, you can test it yourself. Or here is the video, where I'm holding "Backspace" button with enabled and disabled status panel https://i.imgur.com/HSuMH83.gifv

Comment: Ah, sure. You mean the **Paragraphs** count is very slow, not the lines count. Yes, it's like that, you can see in the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,682) (from TextBoxBase, that's where the method comes from => a *generic* method) what kind of calcultation is performed each time you ask for the number of paragraphs (and you cannot thread this, you'll have to Invoke() anyway, blocking everything). You'll have to go down to the native `RichEdit` control to get that information in a more *digestible* way.

Comment: @Jimi But why when I using this code `int line = 1 + richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine());` I have quick response. And when I use this `int linesCount = richTextBox.Lines.Length;` i have slow response? 

And then how to make this code `int line = 1 + richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine());` react to word wrap in richtextbox?

Comment: `GetLineFromCharIndex` sends a `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` message to the RTB. Meaning, this information is readily available. As you have noted, a `Line` is a reference to a physical line of text (a line of text as presented in the RTB client area, subject to wrapping). These are the references that the control cares about and thus kepps track of. The Paragraph itself is treated more as a selection of text than a section of text separated by a line feed. A Paragraph can span more than one section of text separated by a line feed. There is no cached reference (that I'm aware of) to a logical line.

Comment: This: `richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine())` is the same as `richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart)`. In this case, too, the selection can span more than one logical line of text. You can check, if interested, whether `GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart)` returns a differnt value than `GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionEnd)` (so, there's an active selection that spans more chars)

Comment: I'm actually interested to verify whether you can get back a reference to the number of logical lines without pasing the whole text (as you have seen in the .Net source code - it's done like that because the control doesn't provide a method or a native message that returns that information). But the native RichEdit control's (not just the .Net derived one) implementation of the TOM (the Windows Text Object Model) is partial at best.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code and I can not understand why do you create a new RichTextBox every time you call `StatusPanelTextInfo` method:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox
{
    WordWrap = false,
    Text = richTextBox1.Text
};
```

This is the reason you got such a lag in your program. Each time you change/select text, you create a new RichTextBox object and copy a large amount of text to its Text property. You should remove this code, and then it works fast enough. Just replace `rtb` in your calculation of `currentLine` with `richTextBox1`.

Next time please provide your code in your question instead of making people download it from outer link. Your whole form class was about 60 lines. With proper selection you could have given us all the info we needed using 20 lines.

Comment: Im creating another richtextbox because this code: `currentLine = 1 + richtextbox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.SelectionStart);` does not work with wordwrap option. And I already told that in comments in first post. Even if I delete this part of code, this does not help to improve performance. I alredy tested it. So this is not a solution.

Comment: Works perfectly without creating new object instances. Tested with richTextBox1.Length up to 100,000,000. You are creating another richtextbox for what reason? Only to get the required value? Why not add some code and calculate it correctly, without creating new RichTextBox instances for no reason?

Comment: It appears to me that you are asking the wrong question. You actually need to know "How to get the current line of rtb with word wrap". Not asking the question you have the right answer to.

Comment: 1) Here is the video https://i.imgur.com/HSuMH83.gifv where I tested performance without part of code what creates new richtextbox. 2) My question is still the same: Performance issues when calculating line number, using this code `linesCount = richTextBox1.Lines.Length`